# В чем отличие косвенной адресации от прямой при вызове методов класса?

Tags: c++, классы, объекты

Недавно было выдано задание по програмированиию:

> Программа должна включать в себя статический и динамический способы
>   создания объектов, и для каждого объекта использовать прямую и
>   косвенную адресацию при вызове методов класса

Вопрос в следующем: каково отличие косвенной адресации от прямой? И если можно пример использования прямой и косвенной адресации при вызове методов класса.

Comment: можно было просто погуглить и прочитать подробную информацию

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, там всё понятно написано, не спорю, но например возможна ли прямая адресация при динамическом способе создания объектов?
Если да, не могу понять как её сделать.

Comment: int v = 5;  // объявили

Comment: int *p = &v; // взятие адреса

Comment: std::cout << v; прямая адресация

Comment: std::cout << *p; косвенная адресация

Comment: А вот что имелось в виду про методы, не понятно немножко

Comment: @JaponDemon методы у нашего препода = функции-члены класса

Comment: @JaponDemon прямая адресация на динамический объект/переменную
типо
int *a = new int;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct T {
    int a{5};
};

int main()
{    
    cout << (new T)->a; // прямая адресация
    T* p = new T;
    cout << (*p).a;  // косвенная адресация
    ...
```

По моему так 
P.S. ну пусть вместо a будет какой то метод класса - это несущественно

Comment: исправьте `*p.a` на `(*p).a`

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, да, я забыл,  спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Статическое создание объекта происходит в куче, а динамическое в свободной памяти.

```
int x; - статический объект
new T; - динамический
```

Прямой метод класса, как и статический вызывается независимо от состояния объекта (сын он или отец класса). Косвенный вызов изучает родословную объекта и вызывается для каждого состояния индивидуально.

```
T a; a.f(); - прямо
static void f(T x); T::f(a); - прямо
virtual void f(); a.f(); - косвенно
```